# Difference between CI and CID in gsm

Tags: gsm

Can anyone tell what the difference between CID and CI in the picture below :

[image]

Comment: please respond to every reply you receive. Accept and upvote if you think answer might help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

CID is the cell id, the unique number to indicate the base transceiver station.

you can find more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_ID).

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this same question while using GNet Track Android app. If I'm not wrong, CI means BSIC, while CID, as Mathews pointed, refers to Cell ID. My guess is just especulation, what means that I'm not very sure (it would be nice if someone which knows the answer comments in order to solve the question for those who arrive this same post with the same question since, at least me, have not been able to find any information about this topic), because this answer is based on the observation that CI contains the same value that BSIC in the app, and is also based in the fact that in the documentation of the app does not make any reference to "CI", and the documentation is very complete about all the parameters which shows.

Check 4.3 [here](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/123000_123099/123003/15.04.00_60/ts_123003v150400p.pdf) for more information about CID and BSIC.